# HTML - Table Cell Sizes

Tags: html

My table is supposed to look like this:

[image: this]

How do I get the track listing numbers to sit so tightly in that cell?  I've tried colspan and rowspan and can't get it to sit that comfortably.

Also, I have not included the table headers in my HTML above but I do have it. There are 2 table headers, yet 3 columns underneath the header. How do I get it all to sit together nicely as in the picture I linked, and not like mine?

Thanks!

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Thunder Road</td>
        <td>4:47</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>10th Avenue Freeze Out</td>
        <td>3:10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Night</td>
        <td>3:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Backstreet</td>
        <td>6:29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Born To Run</td>
        <td>4:29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>She's The One</td>
        <td>4:29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Meeting Across The River</td>
        <td>3:15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Jungleland</td>
        <td>9:33</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean "numbers to sit so tightly in that cell"? Please add all the code, and the code for the headers.

Comment: The external image is gone, so the requirements are no longer clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to add `colspan="2"` on the `<td>` that writes "Bruce Springsteen...", which means that this cell will take the place of 2 columns.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Bruce Springsteen<br>Born To Run</td>
    <td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7a/Born_to_Run_(Front_Cover).jpg"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Thunder Road</td>
    <td>4:47</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10th Avenue Freeze Out</td>
    <td>3:10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Night</td>
    <td>3:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Backstreet</td>
    <td>6:29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Born To Run</td>
    <td>4:29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>She's The One</td>
    <td>4:29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Meeting Across The River</td>
    <td>3:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>Jungleland</td>
    <td>9:33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```